# javascript module pattern vs function

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

Compare these two codes
First:

```
function initializeView() {}
function init() {
    initializeView();
}
```

Second:

```
function init() {
    (function initializeView() {})();
}
```

If initializeView() only invoked inside the init(), then which one is better?
(I think they did the same work)

EDIT:
I didn't think about global namespace at the first place cuz all of them are inside the Class.

```
var MyObject = (function() {
    ...
    function init() {}
    ...
})();
```

Comment: It depends if you need it in global scope or not.

Comment: How often are they invoked? Does it help anything if `initializeView` is a closure inside `init`?

Comment: Not often. I don't think it help anything. Both of them work but don't know which is better. @Bergi

Answer (score 2):

The first pollutes the global namespace with an unnecessary variable, while the second creates unnecessary closures and/or creates an additional function object on every invocation of `init`.

Assuming that `initializeView` is called only once per `init()` (as your IEFE suggests), it would be better to simply inline the code.

If you need it as a function to invoke multiple times, I'd recommend

```
var init = (function() {
    function initializeView() {}
    return function init() {
        …
        initializeView();
        …
    };
}());
```

Comment: Closures FTW.  Also, it should be noted that while some people name IEFE like in the original code, I find it to be bad practice.

Comment: Why would named functions be a bad practice? They're helpful in debugging and keep the code expressive, I don't care if IE has problems with them.

Comment: I am talking about like `var init = (function MyFunc() { //code }());` ... to me this isn't readable and can cause confusion.

Comment: Well, if the function is named reasonably then it helps to avoid confusion - it's clear what `initializeView` does and it returns nothing. Sure, most IEFEs don't need explicit naming, but it can be useful.

Comment: I know i can simply don't use initializeView() and write those codes inside the init(), there will be no difference. What i'm trying to do is structure nicely. Use function can make the code easier to read. I just don't know what people usually do in my scenario.